# Unclaimed status in PayPal Sandbox account

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

We are using PayPal rest SDK to capture payments. Earlier, we had USD as currency and when made dummy transactions with it, status used to appear COMPLETED. Since the client is from the UK, we tried the GBP currency and from that day, the status is appearing as **UNCLAIMED** on the transaction page in the sandbox account. The API response is appearing properly though.

Its UK account and the default currency is GBP.

Please let me know what could be the problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the transaction currency is GBP and it's unclaimed, the most likely cause is that receiving account does *not* have GBP as a currency balance (primary or otherwise). Open a GBP balance in that [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) account interface.

Another possible reason for an unclaimed payment is the email address of the receiver being unconfirmed within the [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.

First point:
In the sandbox account, the primary currency is GBP.

Second point:
If email address confirmation is the problem, then why it's working (status is COMPLETED) when I pass USD as currency while making transaction?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct client id for the correct sandbox account?

Comment: Thank you so much for the response again. Let me double-check it with the developer and get back to you.

Comment: I checked with the developer and there was a mismatch with the account id. The account he said he used for making transactions has GBP as primary currency but he was actually using a different account (which has another currency as primary). Thank you so much for the answer and support. Really helpful.